# Problem importing input from html: Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, html, express, import

Actually my code is this, I'm conecting via post method to request the JWT token, until now it has only worked with hardcoded data input.
I'm trying to get the input from index.html but it shows me this error:

````
import express from "express";
import axios from 'axios';

let token = '';
const app = express();
const PORT = 5000; 
app.use(express.json());
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log("Server started at %s", PORT));

const login = document.querySelector('#login');
    const valueLogin = login.value;

    const senha = document.querySelector('#senha');
    const valueSenha = senha.value;

const authenticate = async (login,senha) => {
    try {
        await axios('API WEB link',
        {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { "Content-Type":'application/json'},
            auth: {
                username: login,
                password: senha,
            },
        }).then((response) => {
            token = response.data
            console.log(token);
        });
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
}

async function main(){
await authenticate(valueLogin, valueSenha);
        
    }

main();```
````

Comment: Did you set `"type": "module"` in `package.json`?

Comment: Yes, i did.

```{
  "name": "InterfaceStrateegiaGoogleNode28082021",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}```

Comment: Wait a sec... I am looking at your code and cannot understand where it must to run. I see `express` and `querySelector`. Is this all in one file?

Comment: I have one HTML file where i have a form.
A friend helped me importing express and axios so i can make the http request and it worked with harded code.
But now i'm trying to inport the data fom index html to set them as variable e pass this values into the authetication.

Comment: At the first line i have this code:
```import express from "express";```